# Julia function not capturing all variables in scope

Tags: julia

I'm having a strange issue where only some of the global variables in scope are available to the callback function.  I figure I'm missing a key concept of scoping in julia but need some guidance.

```
include("./bootstrap.jl")

using Dates

dt = Dates.now()
date = Date(dt)
startCalcTime = Time(dt)
guiUpdateInterval = Dates.Second(15)

function create_algo(date::Date)
    1, 2
end

algo, t = create_algo(date)

b = 1
a = 5

global nextGuiUpdateDateTime = date + startCalcTime

function callback(p1, p2)
    @show algo
    @show a
    @show nextGuiUpdateDateTime # not defined ?????
    @show b

    # if you comment this out it seems to work??
    if Dates.now() > nextGuiUpdateDateTime
        nextGuiUpdateDateTime += guiUpdateInterval
    end
end

callback(nothing, nothing)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the `nextGuiUpdateDateTime` is a local variable in the `callback` function because you assign to it. See:

```
julia> @code_warntype callback(nothing, nothing)
MethodInstance for callback(::Nothing, ::Nothing)
  from callback(p1, p2) @ Main REPL[15]:1
Arguments
  #self#::Core.Const(callback)
  p1::Core.Const(nothing)
  p2::Core.Const(nothing)
Locals
  value@_4::Union{}
  value@_5::Union{}
  value@_6::Any
  value@_7::Any
  nextGuiUpdateDateTime::Union{}
```

You need to declare it `global` when you assign value to it:

```
function callback(p1, p2)
    @show algo
    @show a
    @show nextGuiUpdateDateTime # not defined ?????
    @show b

    # if you comment this out it seems to work??
    if Dates.now() > nextGuiUpdateDateTime
        global nextGuiUpdateDateTime += guiUpdateInterval
    end
end
```